# How do I *set* a differently scoped variable within a template in Angular 12+

Tags: angular

As the title suggests, I need to be able to set a variable in an angular template (the html) and access that variable later - by a global scope, or some other means. Be nice....I'm new to Angular

**Edit**

Of the few things I've tried is to set a local variable via an input tag, but when I try to access this outside of the div it was created in, Angular doesn't recognise it. Error is: Property 'aVariable' does not exist on type

```
<div>
 <input #aVariable name="aVariable">
</div>
<div>
<span>{{aVariable}}</span> <----Property 'aVariable' does not exist on type-->
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="scenario[s]">
  <td *ngIf="list[i].dscenarios" [attr.colspan]="dColumnKeys.length">

    <!-- Begin table -->
    <table class="table table-hover mat-elevation-z8">

      <!-- Scenario table header -->
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let col of tColumnKeys" scope="col">{{col}} </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <!-- Scenario table body -->
      <tbody>

        <!-- Outer container for looping through stuff -->
        <ng-container *ngFor="let ts of list[i].dscenarios![s].films; let t = index">
            
            <!-- I want to set aVariable here in this scope -->
            
        </ng-container>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</ng-container>


<div [ngClass]="{'d-none': aVariable === false}" class="input-container">

  <!-- I want to get aVariable here in this scope -->
  
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col">
      <form [formGroup]="threatForm">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried loads today and still haven't mananged to do what I needed. Doing it in Javascript is easy, but not in Angular....

Answer (score 0):

Angular templates don't define variables, they just references properties and methods of the component class. Even if it's like the example above to just "bounce" the value from an input to a span, it should go and come from the component.

The component .ts file:

```js
@Component(.....)
export class SomeComponent {
    //Declare a variable to be used in the template
    public inputValue: string = "";

    //And other non relevant things here
}
```

And in the template itself:

```html
<div>
    <input [(ngModel)]="inputValue"> <!-- saves value to "inputVariable" -->
</div>
<div>
    <span>{{inputValue}}</span>  <!-- reads value from "inputVariable" -->
</div>
```

Comment: I understand - thank you, however I still am unsure of how to set the variable in the component from the template. In your temp[late example - how do I update the value of the inputValue? I've tried the following but it never updates: <input [(ngModel)]="inputValue" value="bar">

Comment: Since it's bound though the `ngModel` every time you type something in the textbox it'll automatically reflect on the variable (and in turn, in the span). If you want to change it programatically, just change in the component like any other variable. For an initial value you can change it in the declaration, like `public inputValue: string = "bar";`.

Comment: I'm trying to change it in the template - not in the component. And its not a textbox - I;m just trying anything that will change a value in the component from the template

Comment: I really don't mind what method is used....I just want to do this:
Component: aVariable
Template: aVariable="something"

Comment: @ma11achy The template is just a piece of HTML, it doesn't change things in the component, only tells the browser what to render. The only things that influence the component from the template is user action (though bindings in input tags, click handlers in buttons and the like).

Comment: What's exactly what you're trying to do here?

Comment: Sorry - maybe I'm not being clear enough. I've posted another question here, to clarify as much as possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71271471/change-component-variable-in-template-in-angular-12

Comment: Seeing the edit, my answer remains the same. **Templates don't declare variables**, the component does, templates just take variables from the component and write to them though user input (from HTML inputs). There is no such thing as "local variable" in templates.

Comment: So something as simple as a script tag in javascript with a var declared and chnaged within the html can't be done in Angular??

Comment: It can be done (with a `<script>` tag, not an `<input>`), but should never be done. All javascript code **must** reside in components, while the templates only hold plain HTML. When developing in Angular you don't write separate .js files or do any direct DOM manipulation, you encapsulate the code in the component and the HTML in templates. As a framework, Angular is very opinionated and will "force" to do things in its way. And the Angular's way to declare variables is the component.